# Extract list item from nested json/dictionary in python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a json in python that looks like the following:

```
{
  "Id": "123",
  "fields": {
    "List1": [{
        "List2": [
          {
            "List3": [
              { "item":"1",
                "Activation": False
                },
              { "item":"2",
                "Activation":True
               },
              { "item":"3",
                "Activation":False
               },               
]}]}]}}
```

How can I write a function that return the count of Activation:False?
So in this example, it will return 2, since there are two items that have Activation:False.

so something like:

```
def count_false:
    #code to count false
    return count
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is just a series of list and dictionary lookups and a loop. Was there a particular problem when you tried to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function will recursively look for the key 'Activation' and return the amount of false Activations.

```
def count_false(your_obj):
    count = 0
    if isinstance(your_obj, dict):
        for k, v in your_obj.items():
            if k == 'Activation':
                count += 1 if v is False else 0
            elif isinstance(v, list):
                for e in v:
                    count += count_false(e)
            elif isinstance(v, dict):
                count += count_false(v)
    return count
```

you can also solve this with a regular expression:

```
import re
import json

def count_false(your_obj):
    json_string = json.dumps(your_obj)
    matches = re.findall(r'"Activation": false\b', json_string)
    return len(matches)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below

```
data = {
    "Id": "123",
    "fields": {
        "List1": [{
            "List2": [
                {
                    "List3": [
                        {"item": "1",
                         "Activation": False
                         },
                        {"item": "2",
                         "Activation": True
                         },
                        {"item": "3",
                         "Activation": False
                         },
                    ]}]}]}}

num_of_false_activation = sum(1 for x in data['fields']['List1'][0]['List2'][0]['List3'] if x['Activation'] is False)
print(num_of_false_activation)
```

output

```
2
```

Comment: how do i deal with the "TypeError: string indices must be integers" error

Comment: There is no general answer to this question. Did you get it while you run my code?

Comment: I got the error when I tried to use it as a udf in pyspark. May be other issues involved. Thanks for the solution.